# How to reduce time of algorithm execution

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have to wirte an algorithm, which finding two nearest points on earth. I wrote the code below and it works for my tests, but the time of execution is too long. I tried to modify the code, but it didn't help. Maybe someone will have an idea what should I do?

```
struct Points
{
    std::string key;
    double latitude;
    char latSign;
    double longitude;
    char longSign;
};

typedef std::pair<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, double> myType;

double toFraction(short deegres, short minutes)
{
    return (double)deegres + (minutes / 60.0);
}

double orthodroma(const Points &a, const Points &b)
{
    double radian = M_PI / 180;
    return acos((cos((90 - a.latitude) * radian) *
                 cos((90 - b.latitude) * radian)) +
                (sin((90 - a.latitude) * radian) *
                 sin((90 - b.latitude) * radian) *
                 cos((a.longitude - b.longitude) * radian))) *
           (180 / M_PI);
}

bool sortByLatitude(const Points &a, const Points &b)
{
    return a.latitude > b.latitude;
}

myType bruteForce(const std::vector<Points> &vec, int begin, int n)
{
    myType result;
    double min = 1000000;
    int _i, _j;
    if(n > 300)
    {
    }
    for(int i = begin; i < (n + begin) - 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < n + begin; j++)
        {
            double tmp;
            tmp = orthodroma(vec[i], vec[j]);
            if(tmp < min)
            {
                min = tmp;
                _i = i;
                _j = j;
            }
        }
    }
    result.first.first = vec[_i].key;
    result.first.second = vec[_j].key;
    result.second = min;
    return result;
}

myType divideAndConquer(std::vector<Points> &vec, int begin, int n)
{
    if(n <= 3)
    {
        return bruteForce(vec, begin, n);
    }
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), sortByLatitude);
    int middle = n / 2;
    Points point = vec[middle];
    myType left = divideAndConquer(vec, begin, middle);
    myType right = divideAndConquer(vec, middle, (n - middle));
    bool which;
    double minDist = std::min(left.second, right.second);
    if(left.second < right.second)
        which = false;
    else
        which = true;
    std::vector<Points> arr;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(abs(vec[i].latitude - point.latitude) < minDist)
        {
            arr.push_back(vec[i]);
        }
    }
    int size = arr.size();
    if(size < 2)
    {
        if(which)
            return right;
        else
            return left;
    }
    else
    {
        myType one = bruteForce(arr, 0, size);
        if(which)
        {
            if(one.second < right.second)
                return one;
            else
                return right;
        }
        else
        {
            if(one.second < left.second)
                return one;
            else
                return left;
        }
    }
}
```

PS. I have to use divide an conquer method.

Comment: Please describe the problem you have, and what solution are you using.

Comment: Have you compiled the code in optimised mode?

Comment: The problem is a time of execution. The program gets a data at the input and has to fit within the specified time (6.20 sec), but my execution time is about 7.99 sec and I'm looking for solution how to improve it.

Comment: Make a fast estimate and only calculate the true value if it is close.

Comment: Store the latitudes in radians instead of converting every time they're used.

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas that might improve the performance a little bit:

- sort the array only once (before the first recursive call to the divide and conquer method).
- when adding points into the `arr` vector, you can start from the middle position, first moving forward, and afterwards moving backward. The advantage is that you can break each of these loops as soon as one point is far enough from the middle point. Since the array is sorted by latitude, it is guaranteed that the rest of the points will be outside the desired range.
- you can pass an additional parameter to the divideAndConquer method, representing the minimum distance known so far. This can lead to smaller `arr` arrays, quicker to process. Currently, it might be the case that we get a very small distance for the left sub-array. However, when solving the right sub-array, the recursive calls currently have no information about that small distance already found.

Answer (score 0):

To find the nearest two points you need to first check distance to the nearest point for each point.

You should use a KD tree for fast nearest neighbor lookups.  You can use comparable distance to save a sqrt() operation.

This is a great [kd tree library](https://github.com/nvmd/libkdtree)